# How to add date time values in csv from json using python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv

I am trying to convert a nested json with multiple arrays and object jsons into CSV file using python. I tried many methods somehow i got the csvfile with only 1 array. I want to print the many filters which has unique values inside , so i am not able to print the 2nd arrays with cost, my sample json as below :

SAMPLE JSON:

```
     {
    "breakdown":[
     {
     "filter":"tags",
     "cost":5517.734,
     "values":[
        {
           "count":13,
           "subvalues":[
              {
                 "count":1,
                 "subvalue":"BizOps-VM-20",
                 "cost":227.576
                  {
                 "count":4,
                 "subvalue":"<nulltagvalue>",
                 "cost":70.358
              },
                 "subvalues":[
              {
                 "count":2,
                 "subvalue":"cb",
                 "cost":4.584
              }
           ],
           "cost":4.584,
           "value":"TagNewForTestw"
           }
           ]   
           },
             {
        "filter":"account",
        "cost":2954.905,
        "values":[
        {
           "count":86,
           "cost":1613.508,
           "value":"628455167342"
         },]
         },
       "time":[
        {
        "cost":112.793,
       "time":"2017-05-16"
       },
      {
      "cost":112.748,
     "time":"2017-05-17"
        },
        {
       "cost":112.739,
       "time":"2017-05-18"
       },  
      ]
```

now here i have time array where time and cost is in json i want this to print in csv using python code , but when trying to print i am getting ###### format in place of time values. and one more thing is that i am getting repeated time values printed even after the end of array time.

My python code :

```
      import json
      import csv
      import time
      f = open('cost_drilldown_data.json')            
      data = json.load(f)
      s=csv.writer(open('cd13old.csv','w'))
      s.writerow(["filter","cost","value","cost","subvalue","cost"])
      i=0
      for breakdown in data['breakdown']:
           for values in breakdown['values']:
              if 'subvalues' in values:
                  for subvalues in values['subvalues']:
                      for time in data['time']:                     
                        s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],breakdown["cost"],
                       values['value'],values['cost'],subvalues["subvalue"],
                       subvalues["cost"],time['time'],time['cost']])
              else :       
      s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],"","",values['value'],values['cost']])
```

The output is :

```
filter,cost,value,cost,subvalue,cost,time,cost
```

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-16,112.793

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-17,112.748

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-18,112.739

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-19,107.165

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-20,89.988

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-21,88.773

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-22,96.591

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-23,104.809

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-24,104.471

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-25,104.472

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-26,103.536

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-27,83.205

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-28,83.103

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-29,83.111

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-30,84.555

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-31,86.986

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-01,103.024

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-02,100.905

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-03,102.062

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-04,105.243

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-05,105.134

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-06,111.764

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-07,107.455

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-08,107.62

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-09,107.61

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-10,102.53

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-11,102.282

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-12,105.52

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-13,93.617

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-06-14,41.094

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,,70.358,2017-05-16,112.793

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,,70.358,2017-05-17,112.748

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,,70.358,2017-05-18,112.739

its printing the values again and again , i tried using iteration but not abe to get stop the repition of values. So anybody can help or guide me here i am stuck

THE EXPECTED OUT PUT IS :

filter,cost,value,cost,subvalue,cost,time,cost

tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps-VM-20,227.576,2017-05-16,112.793
tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,,70.358,2017-05-16,112.793
tags,5517.734,Name,462.62,BizOps01,60.188,2017-06-10,102.53

Comment: The problem is likely to be in the input data. But as your sample contains too much problems (missing commas, incoherent indentation, uncomplete json), I cannot tell you more. Please write a valid json input and fix its indentation if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Done indentation pls forgive that json as it is huge data which i cant paste here pls guide me how to use if loop to satisfy the empty keywords

Comment: This islike i want to  print the filters :account and following many filters are there is it good using ifloop or i can use for loop
Any sugggestions or help is needed as i am stuck in this!!

Comment: Please fix your input string so it is valid json. Now it is impossible to parse it. I doubt anyone will help you unless you provide a valid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('cd13old.csv','w') as csvfile:
    s=csv.writer(csvfile)
    s.writerow(["filter","cost","value","cost","subvalue","cost"])
    for breakdown in data['breakdown']:
        for values in breakdown['values']:
            if 'subvalues' in values:
                for subvalues in values['subvalues']:
                    s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],values['value'],values['cost'],subvalues["subvalue"],subvalues["cost"]])
            else:
                s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],values['value'],values['cost'],"",""])
```

Comment: yes for that only i am asking  help on how to modify i tired some if condition like if 'subvalues' not in breakdown :
               continue
s.writerow(".....")
But its not going inside if i put this below
for subvalues in values['subvalues']:
            if 'sub values' not in subvalues:
                    continue
                s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],breakdown["cost"],values['value'],values['cost'],subvalues["subvalue"],subvalues["cost"]])

Comment: can you pls help on this

Comment: for breakdown in data['breakdown']:
    for values in breakdown['values']:
        for subvalues in values['subvalues']:      # if subvalues not in values:
            if 'subvalues' not in 'values':
                break
            s.writerow([breakdown['filter'],breakdown["cost"],values['value'],values['cost'],subvalues["subvalue"],subvalues["cost"]])
i have tried this but also not coming

Comment: for breakdown in data['breakdown']:
                    for values in breakdown['values']:
                  for subvalues in values['subvalues']['values']:      # if subvalues not 
         in values:
            if 'subvalues' not in 'values':
                 break


ERROR:
    for subvalues in values['subvalues']['values']:      # if subvalues not in values:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: kirsz thanks a lot really it helped me to sort out the error , you are great !!! thanks for the help , i will understand from your coding on how to code ,

Comment: I made a mistake by writing the if condition below the 3rd for loop and also dint get the mind for the else statement

Comment: and can i know for what you are adding the "","" line n else statement what is the function of that , pls let me understand thanks

Comment: @flower those are just empty strings in place of missing values, that should come from 'subvalue'. This is to make the csv file consistent - with the same number of elements in every row.

Comment: @k.krsz please see the edited doubt in the same code. and kindly help me i tried a lot but not able to . thats why approached as i am new to python

Comment: @flower first of all - fix your indentation. 2nd why are you iterating over the `data['time']`?

Comment: I have done the indentation. sorry!! and i have iterated through it because the time is in an array format. correct me if i am wrong please

Comment: So how do you want your output to look now? The one you provided looks ok to me. You print one line for each separate ['time'] value

Comment: actually in excell sheet the date is coming ##### format for 1/12/2017 format and it is repeating again and again. how to make it print only one time.

Comment: Well, for that you would have to ask some Excel specialist - i have no clue why this could happen

Comment: Its ok thanks for your response and help . you made to solve off the previous problem thanks a lott!!!!!